# PHP regex: How to whitelist alphanumeric characters?

Tags: php, regex, whitelist

Can anyone tell me why 1 (blacklist) does not throw an unexpected end error and 2 (white list) does?  1 is not filtering out all the special characters so I want to use a whitelist approach.  The error I'm getting seems to be related to syntax but I cannot spot it.  Thank you for helping to end my misery.

```
php

(1)
if (preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $posteduid))
{
$error = "You may not use special characters in your username";
}

(2)
if (!preg_match("#^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$#", $posteduid))
{
$error = "You may not use special characters in your username";
}
```

error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /.../join.php on line 346
```

Comment: What is an example of your input.

Comment: user# would be something I would want to filter out.  However, the page throws an error even before giving it any input.

Comment: Nothing wrong in this regex

Comment: What's the error, exactly? Can you edit your post with it?

Comment: When I comment out 1 and use 2, it throws error.  When I comment out 2 and use 1, no error.  The unexpected end mentioned in the error message is at the very end of the document so something seems to be throwing off the opening and closing braces...

Comment: i think you need to escape the slashes in the regex string

Comment: `?>` this is the end of php tag, **no exceptions**.

Comment: which string?  Case 1 does not throw error.  Case 2 does.

Comment: i understood that string one throws the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you comment out this line

```
if (preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $posteduid))
```

using `//` it will still see the `?>` and stops parsing PHP, resulting in an weird error. Just remove that part or use `/* */`-comments. There is nothing wrong with your code-sample on the white list.

Comment: If you use an editor with code-coloring like Notepad++ or an IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse (all free to download) and you see immediately that kind of mistakes.